# Install SSAS on Personal Computer

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I want to install MS SQL Analysis Service Agent on my laptop.

I have downloaded latest SQL Server 2014 file -- **SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU (1).exe**

But I am not able to install the Analysis Service feature. I have checked online and it shows that while installing in **Features** =, I could find Analysis Service as on of them, but I don't find that. Follwoing is the screen shot of the Feature Selection window.

Feature Selection Window - SQL Server 2014 Setup - Please view
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSAS is shipped with Enterprise, BI, Standard, and developer editions only. Once you get a right edition you will see option to select Analysis services, and its mode.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Express with Advance Tool Service doesn't contain SSAS and SSIS

[Check it here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2014/03/10/adding-sql-server-express-2012-advanced-services-to-existing-development-environment/)

You can use Developer Edition which is free from now on.